# Why does Visual Studio 2017 not have ActionController and ManageController

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2013, when I tried making a web app using ASP.NET MVC, there were 3 default controllers:

HomeController
ActionController
ManageController

Now in VS 2017, I only have the 1st one.

Do I no longer need controllers 2 and 3 for authentication? I am trying to create Role Based application.

Comment: ActionController or AccountController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating the new MVC project change the authentication option to `Individual User Accounts` , like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folders and libraries set up when creating a new project are "scaffolded" based on what options you chose when creating the project. Did you opt-in to using Authentication when creating the project? Else, the folders will not be added automatically.

However, you can still add them manually. [Adding Identity to an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617002/adding-identity-to-an-existing-project?noredirect=1&lq=1)